# Virtualbox freezes host for a few seconds

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in virtualbox as my development machine (including unity and gui software). I am running Windows 10 (latest update) as my host system.

Sometimes, my entire PC hangs for a few seconds. This is virtualbox related, because it does not occur if VB is closed. Everything is non responsive, sometimes including the mouse, sometimes not. The task manager screen does not show an extreme load, and I have not been able to determine a precise cause.

Both machines have plenty of memory (32 GB total, 16GB for the guest). VT-x/AMD-V is enabled. 3d acceleration is enabled. The virtualbox helper tools are installed in the guest.

Anybody know why this happens and how to solve?